# How to add formatters of html elements to column headers with the method to_html in order to rotate them?

Tags: css, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, bootstrap-4

I am using a Pandas DataFrame and I want to show it in a html page showing as less empty space as possible. I am also using Bootstrap 4

I can add formatters to all the elements of a column with the [`to_html` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html?highlight=to_html), and table styles:

```
html = df.to_html(
    formatters={'COL_NAME': lambda x: '<b>' + x + '</b>'},
    classes='table table-striped df_data',
    escape=False
)
```

And I can add html elements as well replacing the values directly

```
html = html.replace('<th>', '<th><div><span>')
html = html.replace('</th>', '</span></div></th>')
```

- Is there a clean way to add these html elements to the headers?
- I am doing all of this to show rotated headers and save screen space as in the picture. I took the css styles [from this page](https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/)

  [image: oblique_headers]

  ```
  .df_data thead th {
      height: 140px;
      white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .df_data thead th > div {
      transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
      width: 30px;
  }

  .df_data thead th > div > span {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  ```

  But the result is far from the expected. The space is not safed and the headers are not aligned. What I need to do to safe the free space in the columns? I will need to forget about Bootstrap styles
- Is there a straight forward way to achieve this?

Any recommendation will be appreciated

## Update 2019-26-02

The solution of @joshmoto is a good approach but I need adapting width columns because I do not know the cell contents beforehand (10 characters as maximum)

[image: width_headers]

Comment: Not sure if this is what your after? https://www.codeply.com/go/xAcSmgWrfK

Comment: Thank you @joshmoto, I have updated my question with more details

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/go/RuEciHdXo3 what about this?

Comment: I could make it work pretty well thank you. If you post it as an answer I will accept it @joshmoto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this desired effect when the cell width is variable, you will need to add another div and position that is `position: relative;` in the table header cell. From here you can `position: absolute;` the next child div `left: 100%;`, which will give you your right point of reference. Then you can continue to use the code you provided from the codepen demo.

See codeply working demo here https://www.codeply.com/go/RuEciHdXo3

```css
MAIN {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px
}

.df_data {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

.df_data thead th {
  border-top: none;
  padding: 0
}

.df_data td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}

.df_data th.rotate {
  margin-left: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.df_data th.rotate>div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px
}

.df_data th.rotate>div>div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  transform: translate(-14px, -2px) rotate(315deg)
}

.df_data th.rotate>div>div>span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px
}

.df_data th.row-header {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<main role="main" class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped df_data">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th class="rotate">
          <div>
            <div><span>Column header 1</span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th class="rotate">
          <div>
            <div><span>Column header 2</span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th class="rotate">
          <div>
            <div><span>Column header 3</span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th class="rotate">
          <div>
            <div><span>Column header 4</span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th class="rotate">
          <div>
            <div><span>Column header 5</span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th class="rotate">
          <div>
            <div><span>Column header 6</span></div>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="row-header">Row header 1</th>
        <td>2w98</td>
        <td>3423423</td>
        <td>35325233542947742747344</td>
        <td>12213&gt;</td>
        <td>453842589389582</td>
        <td>49849</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</main>
```